# HTML to Google Document conversion

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to convert an HTML file to a Google Document. My attempt right now was something like:

```
var html_file = DocsList.createFile('myfile.html', data, "text/html");
var docs_file = html_file.getAs('application/??').getBytes();
```

What should be the mimetype for a google docs? Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it isn't possible at this time to convert file to the native Google Docs formats (Document, Spreadsheet, Presentation, etc).